# How to get a random number using openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, cryptography

I am tasked with generating a 64 nit unsigned random number and have to use openssl
I have found the functions RAND_bytes and RAND_seed but do not see how these allow me to generate my number.
I am very new to all this so ask for patience
How do I go about generating my random number ?

I am using VS on Windows 7 with C++

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [OpenSSL Documentation about generating PRNs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Software). Basically it says you can initialize the Generators with `RAND_poll` - which should be called automatically - or use `RAND_seed ` to seed the RNG yourself - which is most likely a bad idea if you are new to this all. Then use `RAND_bytes` to generate 8 Bytes = 64Bit using something like `RAND_bytes(my64bitvar,sizeof(my64bitvar))`, check for errors and you are good to go. Its also a good idea too check the used RNG algorithm and select a stronger one as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Comment: I have UInt64 num; and call RAND_bytes((unsigned char*)&num,size)) - does this sound about right?

Comment: I think so, thought I'm a bit rusty with C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

maybe too late but
`openssl rand -hex 64` gives hex encoded thing

Comment: The OP was asking how to do this natively from within C++ code, assumedly not meaning to call out to another binary.